# Subset pandas df using concatenation of column indices slices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subset, indices

I have a large dataframe that I am trying to subset using only column indices. I am using the following code:

```
df = df.ix[:, [3,21:28,30:34,36:57,61:64,67:]]
```

The code is pretty self explanatory. I am trying to subset the df by keeping columns 3, 21 through 28 and so on. However, I am getting the following error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-44-3108b602b220>", line 1
  df = df.ix[:, [3,21:28,30:34,36:57,61:64,67:]]
                     ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The column indices you want to use `[3,21:28,30:34,36:57,61:64,67:]` are a **concatenation of slices**, not a single slice object, hence not a legal object in pandas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [numpy.r_[...]](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html):

```
df = df.iloc[:, np.r_[3,21:28,30:34,36:57,61:64,67:df.shape[1]]]
```

Demo:

```
In [39]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(5, size=(2, 100)))

In [40]: df
Out[40]:
   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  ...  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99
0   3   1   0   3   2   4   1   2   1   3 ...   2   1   4   2   1   2   1   3   3   4
1   0   2   4   1   1   1   0   0   3   4 ...   4   4   0   3   2   3   0   2   0   1

[2 rows x 100 columns]

In [41]: df.iloc[:, np.r_[3,21:28,30:34,36:57,61:64,67:df.shape[1]]]
Out[41]:
   3   21  22  23  24  25  26  27  30  31 ...  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99
0   3   4   1   2   0   3   0   3   2   2 ...   2   1   4   2   1   2   1   3   3   4
1   1   1   0   2   1   4   4   4   1   3 ...   4   4   0   3   2   3   0   2   0   1

[2 rows x 69 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked great!